# Why doGet(), doPost() Methods are "protected"?

Tags: java

I'm confused about the access modifier of the `doGet()`, `doPost()` and other methods of `HttpServlet` class.

Why are they `protected`?

As per my understanding, the `protected` modifier of `doGet()` means that a client has to be in the same package (or a child - through inheritance) to access `doGet()`. So how will the invoking JSP or the container access it?

Answer (score 11):

They're protected primarily for two reasons.

1. So that external classes can't just call them, like you reasoned. Technically, there are ways to get around method visibility modifiers using Java Reflection (if the Security Manager allows it or there is none), but ordinarily, a protected method can only be accessed by classes in the same package or by subclasses, which brings me to point #2.
2. So that subclasses or concrete implementations of `HttpServlet` can override them.  Well, they can also be overridden if they were public, but see point #1.

Now your other question, "So how will the invoking JSP or the Container access it?"

`HttpServlet` implements the [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) interface, which declares a [service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,+javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) method. This, of course, by default becomes `public` in `HttpServlet`. This is the primary entry point (for containers) to call into `HttpServlet` implementations.

My guess (I haven't dived into the source) is that the default implementation of `HttpServlet` checks the `ServletRequest` object passed in, which is actually an [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and which defines a [`getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) method that returns the HTTP method used. It then dispatches to either `doGet()` or `doPost()` depending on the HTTP request method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's from the official [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

> **Provides an abstract class to be subclassed** to create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at least one method, usually one of these:
>
> doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
>
> doPost, for HTTP POST requests
>
> doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
>
> doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests
>
> init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
>
> getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself

And also

> There's almost no reason to override the service method. service handles standard HTTP requests by dispatching them to the handler methods for each HTTP request type (the doXXX methods listed above).

And in the docs for `doGet` method:

> Called by the server (**via the service method**) to allow a servlet to handle a GET request.

So `HttpServlet` is designed for inheritance and the entry point is the `service` method. Hence `doGet` is protected to enforce clear API.

Comment: No link-only answers please. Can you quote the relevant part here?

Answer (score 2):

doGet and doPost are the basic methods in generating and sending the HttpResponse to the client (i.e usually Browser or HttpClient)

Also, The container calls the `Servlet.service()` method which is `public`. It then calls the `HttpServlet.service()` method which is protected and it then call `doGet()`/`doPost()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I am having a class `MyClass` which is not a servlet, then do I want my class to have methods `doGet` and `doPost`? Well if it's not a servlet then how can it respond or capture any web based requests.

Only servlets can capture and respond to web based requets.

So it makes sense that I will be able to capture and respond to web based requests only if my class extends `Servlet` and and hence I will be able to use `doGet`, `doPost` and variuos other methods.

Comment: well, I understand a class and servlet! Just thinking

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wondering about how the servlet container calls the protected method doGet and doPost.

Actually there is an interface named [javax.servlet.Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html). A class named [GenericServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) implement the interface. And the HTTPServlet class extends this GenericServlet.

When there is an http request to an HTTPServlet, the container simply use the method service(...) declared in the interface. That method is public. Then in the GenericServlet, the service method called doGet and doPost. If your servlet class extends the HTTPServlet class and override the doPost method, then this method will finally get called.

Comment: I think the service method is still abstract in Generic Servlet Class!


The Method Signature Is -

public abstract void service (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)

Comment: Yes, it is abstract, I think HttpServlet overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `protected` as an invitation to override a method. You are deriving a class from `HttpServlet` so these methods are the ones to override. They all have a default action so you can just override the methods which are of interest to your application.